# Error in starting new activity using Intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I have created a menu for my android application. The menu has several buttons, The first buttons should start new Activity called "BackgroundImages" using Intent. However, When I install the app on the emulator and click the button, I receive the following error "Unfortunatlry, NewtonLow has stopped".Moreover, "NewtonLow" is the name of the application. The following demonstrates the steps I did in order to start new Activity.

1. I created a class called Menu which display the the menu.xml layout as follows:

   ```
   public class Menu extends Activity{

      MediaPlayer mp1;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.menu);  
       mp1= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.button );
       Button but1 =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
       but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               mp1.start();
               startActivity(new Intent("ghassar.mohamed.newtonlaw.BACKGROUNDIMAGES"));
           }
       });
   }}
   ```
2. I have edited the Manifast to launch the menu class first as follows:

   ```
       <activity
       android:name=".Menu"
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```

   3. I have also added activity for the backgroundImage class to use it so I can I can start the activity :

      ```
              <activity android:name=".BackgroundImages"android:label="@string/app_name" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="ghassar.mohamed.newtonlaw.BACKGROUNDIMAGES" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFUALT" />
      </intent-filter>
      ```

Logcat error:

```
05-16 12:17:52.242: I/GenericSource(64): start
05-16 12:17:52.274: W/IntentResolver(347): resolveIntent failed: found match, but none with CATEGORY_DEFAULT
05-16 12:17:52.274: I/ActivityManager(347): START u0 {act=ghassar.mohamed.newtonlaw.BACKGROUNDIMAGES} from uid 10053 on display 0
05-16 12:17:52.276: D/AndroidRuntime(2247): Shutting down VM
05-16 12:17:52.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2247): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 12:17:52.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2247): Process: ghassar.mohamed.newtonlaw, PID: 2247
05-16 12:17:52.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2247): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=ghassar.mohamed.newtonlaw.BACKGROUNDIMAGES }
05-16 12:17:52.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1781)
05-16 12:17:52.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
05-16 12:17:52.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
05-16 12:17:52.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
05-16 12:17:52.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
05-16 12:17:52.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
05-16 12:17:52.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at ghassar.mohamed.newtonlaw.Menu$1.onClick(Menu.java:28)
05-16 12:17:52.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
05-16 12:17:52.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
05-16 12:17:52.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
05-16 12:17:52.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-16 12:17:52.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-16 12:17:52.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
05-16 12:17:52.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-16 12:17:52.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-16 12:17:52.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
05-16 12:17:52.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
05-16 12:17:52.324: W/ActivityManager(347):   Force finishing activity 1 ghassar.mohamed.newtonlaw/.Menu
05-16 12:17:52.347: D/AudioSink(64): bufferCount (8) is too small and increased to 12
05-16 12:17:52.495: E/EGL_emulation(53): tid 53: eglCreateSyncKHR(1237): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
05-16 12:17:52.781: I/OpenGLRenderer(347): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-16 12:17:52.827: W/EGL_emulation(347): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-16 12:17:52.827: W/OpenGLRenderer(347): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9f334060, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-16 12:17:53.375: W/ActivityManager(347): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{13745810 u0 ghassar.mohamed.newtonlaw/.Menu t30 f}
05-16 12:17:54.507: W/ResourceType(791): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
05-16 12:17:54.508: W/PackageManager(791): Failure retrieving resources for ghassar.mohamed.newtonlaw: Resource ID #0x0
05-16 12:17:54.590: I/OpenGLRenderer(618): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-16 12:17:54.736: W/EGL_emulation(618): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-16 12:17:54.736: W/OpenGLRenderer(618): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5029520, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-16 12:17:55.144: I/art(618): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2481(214KB) AllocSpace objects, 20(6MB) LOS objects, 24% free, 12MB/16MB, paused 1.176ms total 132.034ms
05-16 12:17:55.553: I/Choreographer(347): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-16 12:17:57.358: I/Choreographer(347): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-16 12:17:57.369: I/Choreographer(347): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-16 12:17:57.585: I/Process(2247): Sending signal. PID: 2247 SIG: 9
05-16 12:17:57.607: D/NuPlayerDriver(64): reset(0xb5915280)
05-16 12:17:57.619: W/InputDispatcher(347): channel '17ecf26e ghassar.mohamed.newtonlaw/ghassar.mohamed.newtonlaw.Menu (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
05-16 12:17:57.619: E/InputDispatcher(347): channel '17ecf26e ghassar.mohamed.newtonlaw/ghassar.mohamed.newtonlaw.Menu (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-16 12:17:57.632: I/ActivityManager(347): Process ghassar.mohamed.newtonlaw (pid 2247) has died
05-16 12:17:57.645: D/NuPlayerDriver(64): notifyResetComplete(0xb5915280)
05-16 12:17:57.673: W/AudioTrack(347): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
05-16 12:17:57.890: I/WindowState(347): WIN DEATH: Window{17ecf26e u0 ghassar.mohamed.newtonlaw/ghassar.mohamed.newtonlaw.Menu}
05-16 12:17:57.890: W/InputDispatcher(347): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '17ecf26e ghassar.mohamed.newtonlaw/ghassar.mohamed.newtonlaw.Menu (server)'
05-16 12:17:58.151: W/InputMethodManagerService(347): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 2247 uid 10053
05-16 12:17:58.200: W/OpenGLRenderer(618): Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
```

Comment: Okay. I will try to copy the errors and I will post them

Comment: declare that activity along with its package name in manifest.

Comment: I have done that but still I keep getting the same error

Comment: `        <action android:name="ghassar.mohamed.newtonlaw.BACKGROUNDIMAGES" />`

Comment: update the manifest and post the manifest along with total activities code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifest, I can see a spelling mistake(DEFUALT instead of DEFAULT)

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="ghassar.mohamed.newtonlaw.BACKGROUNDIMAGES" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```